# Android get spinner value after load?

Tags: android, android-spinner

after load the spinner i want to take the value of spinner which is set in spinner

i know how to get the selected value but when is first time load is get the null value in **time** when is first time load  i want to get the selected value when is first time load

> Spinner part

```
                ArrayAdapter<String>spinnertimeadapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(AirportChekActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,flighttime);
                spinnertimeadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                timespinner.setAdapter(spinnertimeadapter);


                String time;
                timespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {


                        String timeselected=timespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                          Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();    
                          hour=now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                          Log.e("hourrr","-->"+hour);


                          if(hour>=0 && hour<=2)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(0);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=3 && hour<=5)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(1);

                          }

                          else if(hour>=6 && hour<=8)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(2);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=9 && hour<=11)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(3);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=12 && hour<=14)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(4);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=15 && hour<=17)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(5);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=18 && hour<=21)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(6);

                          }
                          else if(hour>=22 && hour<=24)
                          {
                              timespinner.setSelection(7);

                          }

                        stime=timespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        if(timeselected.equals("12:00AM To 3:00AM"))
                        {
                            time="0";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("3:00AM To 6:00AM"))
                        {
                            time="3";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("6:00AM To 9:00AM"))
                        {
                            time="6";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("9:00AM To 12:00PM"))
                        {
                            time="9";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("12:00PM To 3:00PM"))
                        {
                            time="12";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("3:00PM To 6:00PM"))
                        {
                            time="15";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("6:00PM To 9:00PM"))
                        {
                            time="18";
                        }
                        else if(timeselected.equals("9:00PM To 12:00AM"))
                        {
                            time="21";
                        }
                    }
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {



                    }
                }); // time spinner complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the loading time . Please use the following lines in the on create no in the click event.

**Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                          hour=now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                          Log.e("hourrr","-->"+hour);**

So that only you are getting null initially...